# XML Schema requiring explicit values with optional related values

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to construct an XSD that would validate the simplified XML structure below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Ldf
  xmlns="http://www.en-argentina.com.ar/ldf"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.en-argentina.com.ar/ldf
  http://www.en-argentina.com.ar/ldf/ldf8.xsd">
  <Languages>
    <LanguageDetails>
      <Language>
        <name>French</name>
      </Language>
    </LanguageDetails>
  </Languages>
  <Languages>
    <LanguageDetails>
      <Language>
        <name>English</name>
        <Dialect>American English</Dialect>
        <Dialect>British English</Dialect>
      </Language>
    </LanguageDetails>
  </Languages>
</Ldf>
```

In the XSD I want to hard-code the various Languages and their possible Dialects to restrict what goes in the XML.

Each record would require one Language be specified and that Language could have an optional Dialect with zero or more explictly defined values which could be specified. The overall list of languages and dialects will be relatively small.

I thought perhaps using something like `<xsd:restriction>` would allow me to specify the languages and then have a second `<xsd:restriction>` inside the first to handle the dialects, but I have never found any examples of a structure like that while searching for an answer.

The other problem I have is having to import the file into Drupal, i.e., being able to identify the Language and one or more Dialects from a single, common hierarchy no matter what language (and optional dialect(s)) was selected would be crucial.

Any hints/help/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in thinking you want to say: "if the Language is English, then the Dialect must be American English or British English"?

That's a co-occurrence constraint - the value of one element depends on the value of another. As such, it can't be expressed in XSD 1.0, but needs the feature of assertions in XSD 1.1.

Comment: @Micheal, is there any problem using 1.1? For my project I would want people to be able to use something like http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html to validate their XML against my XSD. As long as the format is along the lines of the XML I outlined, 1.1 works for me.

Comment: from recent experience I think I want to avoid using something with `<xs:attribute ref="language"/>` because I have a known and limited universe of possibilities and don't want to permit just any language. I want that language to be A, B or C with the possibility of further assigning nothing or only Dialect D and/or E to language B.  And to answer your original question, yes, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: The only drawback with using 1.1 is if you are locked into a schema processor such as Microsoft's that only supports 1.0.

Comment: Michael, as long as online validators will work, I think I'm in the clear.  Would you happen to know of any examples that I could draw from? I started Googling about the co-occurrence constraint and I found technical discussions and general info, but not a full-blown example that covered my use case.

Comment: Priscilla Walmsley and Mukul Gandhi have both published books on XSD 1.1. They both know their stuff.

Comment: Michael, I'll see if I can get a hold of their work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should works well but only with schema 1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xsd:simpleType name="language_type">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="english"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="ukrainian"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="language">
        <xsd:attribute name="type" type="language_type" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="language_english">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="language">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Dialect" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:enumeration value="value_11"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="value_12"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="value_13"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="value_14"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>

    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="language_ukrainian">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="language">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Dialect" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:enumeration value="value_21"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="value_22"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="value_23"/>
                                <xsd:enumeration value="value_24"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>


    <xsd:element name="Language">
        <xsd:alternative test="@type = 'english'" type="language_english"/>
        <xsd:alternative test="@type = 'ukrainian'" type="language_ukrainian"/>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="Languages">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="Language" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

The result xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Languages xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Language type="english">
        <Dialect>value_11</Dialect>
        <Dialect>value_11</Dialect>
    </Language>
    <Language type="ukrainian">
        <!-- <Dialect>value_11</Dialect> is not valid here-->
        <Dialect>value_21</Dialect>
        <Dialect>value_21</Dialect>
    </Language>
</Languages>
```

Comment: Roman, I tried validating the XML against the XSD here, http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html but I am getting the following error: "S4s-elt-must-match.1: The Content Of 'Language' Must Match (annotation?, (simpleType | ComplexType)?, (unique | Key | Keyref)*)). A Problem Was Found Starting At: Alternative.". Any ideas?

Comment: I think it means they use schema 1.0. For this example version 1.1 is required. That is typical error because "alternative" statement is unknown for schema v. 1.0